# Can the CKM quark mixing matrix be derived?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks

Does the standard model make exact predictions about what the values of the CKM matrix are or are they inferred from experiment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Standard Model has $18$ free parameters that cannot be evaluated directly from the theory. Among this $18$ parameters there are the three mixing angles $\theta_{12}, \theta_{13}, \theta_{23}$ and the phase angle $\delta$ from the CKM matrix.  So, no, the $4$ parameters that define the CKM matrix cannot be evaluated directly from the theory but are found through various experiments.

Answer (score -1):

There is ongoing effort to understand the fundamental origin of the CKM matrix parameters:

CKM matrix parameters from an algebra

https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.00668

Tejinder P. Singh
Tata Institute of Fundamental Research, Mumbai

Comment: Dear Tejinder P. Singh. Welcome to Phys.SE. For your information, Physics.SE has a [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451) that it is OK to cite oneself, but it should be stated clearly and explicitly in the answer itself, not in attached links.